# Rendering all partial views in folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a folder that contains about 20 partial views without any model (just plain javascript/html). Is there a simple way to render all views from a specific folder, for example "/Views/Shared/Forms/...." ?

Comment: +1: interesting question. have you tried listing all files in that folder to list<string> and writing a for loop? i dont know if you have permission to do so actually? just a thought.

Comment: Thought about that, but it will require reading permissions, than passing all view names from controller to a view - hoped to find a simpler way to do it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is another method to render all Partials from a certain folder to a View. However you can do this. (Tested)

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var folderName = "~/Views/Partials/";
    ViewBag.Partials = GetAllViews(folderName);
    return View();
}

private List<string> GetAllViews(string folderName)
{
    var path = Server.MapPath(folderName);
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    return dirInfo.GetFiles().Select(i => folderName + i.Name).ToList();
}
```

View

```
@foreach (string partial in ViewBag.Partials)
{
    //Html.RenderPartial(partial);
    @Html.Partial(partial)
}
```